# Multivariate CDF

Tags: multivariate-analysis, cumulative-distribution-function

I am having difficulties understandomg the following equality:

$$\begin{align*}
 &P\Big(\frac{Z_{1}}{n}+\mu>z,Z_{2}>y,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=3}^{m}Z_{i}+\mu \leq w\Big) \\
&=\int_{n(z-\mu)}^{n(w-\mu)-y} \int_{y}^{n(w-\mu)-z_{1}} P\left(\sum_{i=3}^{m}Z_{i}\leq n(w-\mu)-z_{1}-z_{2}\right) dP^{Z_{2}}(z_{2}) dP^{Z_{1}}(z_{1})
\end{align*}$$

with $0\leq y\leq n(w-z)\,,\, w\geq z\geq \mu$.
Where $\mu,n,m$ are constants, $z,y,w$ are variables and $Z_{i}\sim \text{Exp}(0,\theta)$ are iid random variables.

I believe that more intermediate steps could help my understanding but I  would of course highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You should define the symbols / variables. Eg, I assume $z$ is a standard normal, is that right?

Comment: In addition to defining them, please identify and correct the typographical errors: there are a great many of them.